# Right way of defining a buffer when using sprintf

Tags: c++, arduino

In my Arduino sketch I use `sprintf` to format a reply. The formatted data will be send using SPI.

I have to set the buffer length, but I don't know how large would be good. Here is a piece of the code:

```
  uint8_t myValue = 4;

  // Set buffer
  unsigned char data[1000];
  // Reset this buffer
  memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));

  // Format the reply
  sprintf((char *)data, "This is the int value: %d", \
      myValue);
```

I can also set the buffer to 0 (`unsigned char data[0];`), The code compiles and the reply is the same as using a large buffer. I can't explain this?

It seems `malloc()` and `free()` are pretty rare in the Arduino world...

What is the right way of using a buffer in Arduino?

Comment: You do not need to memset buffer with zero before sprintf sure.

Comment: Sometimes I get weird data from the previous replys. I used this to set the buffer to 0.

Comment: If you set the size of the buffer to 0 with `unsigned char data[0]` then of course you'll get weird data from the previous replies as you're going to be hitting undefined behaviour as you'll be writing the buffer into memory you've not allocated

Comment: @ChrisTurner Hi, The stupid thing is, I get the right data when using a buffer of 0. But, what You say sounds indeed more logical

Comment: yes changed the post @YSC

Comment: An Arduino Uno has only 2kB of memory. You are using half of it just for the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `snprintf` instead, where you specify how large the buffer is. With the current approach `sprintf` assumes that the buffer is large enough, so if you pass it a small buffer it will stomp over some other memory. Not good (and may explain the weird results you sometimes get)!

You can use a fixed buffer as in your current code. Allocating also works, but it has more overhead.

Comment: snprintf is not available in Arduino. I will have a further look into it :)

Comment: Are you sure? There are many posts on the Arduino forums with code using snprintf and if they include sprintf it seems odd to omit snprintf.

Answer (score 0):

> I can also set the buffer to 0 (unsigned char data[0];),

If this is true, you're just getting lucky (or unlucky, depending on how you look at it).   The behaviour of your code doing this is undefined, in both C and C++.    Which, among other things, means it is not guaranteed to work (e.g.  it might break if your compiler is ever updated).

As to better options ....   Your question is tagged C++ and C, and different approaches are preferable in different languages.

Assuming you are using C, and your implementation complies with the 1999 standard or later, you can use `snprintf()`.

```
  char *buffer;
  int length = snprintf((char *)NULL, 0, "This is the int value: %d",  myValue);
  buffer = malloc(length + 1);    /*   +1 allows for terminator */
  snprintf(buffer, length, "This is the int value: %d", myValue);

   /*  use buffer  */
  free(buffer);
```

The first call of `sprintf()` is used to recover the buffer length.   The second to actually write to the allocated buffer.    Remember to release the dynamically allocated buffer when done.   (The above also does not check for errors - `snprintf()` returns a negative value if an error occurs).

If your C library does not include `snprintf()` then (AFAIK) there is no standard way to work out the length automatically - you will need to estimate an upper bound on length by hand (e.g. work out the length of output of the largest negative or positive `int`, and add that to the length of other content in your format string).

In C++, use a string stream

```
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>

 std::ostringstream oss;
 oss << "This is the int value: " << myValue);
 std::string str = oss.str();

 const char *buffer = str.data();

 //   readonly access to buffer here

 //   the objects above will be cleaned up when they pass out of scope.
```

If you insist on using the C approach in C++, the approach above using `snprintf()` can be used in C++ if your implementation complies with the 2011 standard (or later).     However, in general terms, I would NOT recommend this.